# Glassfish resource settings update

Tags: glassfish

If you make changes to a resource setting (the max pool size on a connection pool for example) via the glassfish web interface do you have to restart the app server for the changes to take effect or does it all happen on the fly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many configuration changes can be done on the fly, and if it wants to be restarted it will say so in the top left corner of the admin console, a yellow warning triangle with a "restart required" label.  If that warning is not present there's no need for a restart.